# ReactJS: Input onChange not Updating State

Tags: reactjs

Im running into an issue where the `onChange={}` on `<input />` doesn't change the value through state.

I have two Components, Component 1 passes the the state of an input value to Component 2 as a prop:

Component 1:

```js
function MainContent() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        id="shtitle"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        className="input sh-input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Incident Title"
      />

      <DuplicateHubDisplay
        data={[
          inputValue,
          momentDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A"),
          textareaValue,
        ]}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default MainContent;
```

Component 2: Gets the prop data from Component 1

```js
  const [commsTitle, setCommsTitle] = useState("");
// const [commsTitle, setCommsTitle] = useState(duplicateHubData.data[0]); //Does not work
  
<input
 id="duplicatehub-title"
 value={duplicateHubData.data[0]}
 className="input"
 placeholder="Incident Title"
/>
```

I don't know how to store `duplicateHubData.data[0]` as a state and then use onChange to change the state value.

Doing this does not allow me to change the input value:

```js
const DuplicateHubDisplay = (duplicateHubData) => {
    const [commsTitle, setCommsTitle] = useState(duplicateHubData.data[0]);

    return (
      <input
        id="duplicatehub-title"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCommsTitle(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={commsTitle}
        className="input"
        placeholder="Incident Title"
      />
    );
}
export default DuplicateHubDisplay;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That third option should certainly allow you to update the `commsTitle` state. What or how are you verifying/validating that state isn't updating? In the least you should see the updated state in the input when you are typing. What is `duplicateHubData` in the second component?

Comment: The third method, allows me to update state for sure, however it doesn't contain the data that was provided via ```duplicateHubData.data[0]``` to begin with. Not too sure if something like that needs to wrapped in a useEffect or something so that it renders?

Comment: Can you show us what `duplicateHubData.data[0]` is and where it comes from? Can you also share how the two component snippets relate?

Comment: Is component 2 actually `DuplicateHubDisplay` and being rendered by *some* other component 1?

Comment: Correct, DuplicateHubDisplay is definitely component 2 and component 1 renders DuplicateHubDisplay and passes in those props. 


```duplicateHubData.data[0]``` is the input state from Component 1. 

Basically im trying to replicate Component 1's input value to Component 2's input. The second method by passing in the ```value={duplicateHubData.data[0]}``` replicates Component 1's value, but it doesn't allow me to make edits.

the third method by using state, doesn't even show Component 1s input value however it allows me to update the values

Comment: OK, so what is `duplicateHubData` in the `DuplicateHubDisplay` component (component 2)? You haven't declared it in your snippets. Try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. Try to share both complete components so we can see how they are mounted and how state/props are updated over time.

Comment: Thanks, I have made some changes to the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231766/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ayushlal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want `DuplicateHubDisplay`'s `commsTitle` state to update when either (1) the `inputValue` of the parent component updates or (2) the input value in `DuplicateHubDisplay` updates.

## Issue

`DuplicateHubDisplay` is passed a `data` prop where the initial `inputValue` state value is `""`, so the initial `commsTitle`  state is also `""`. `DuplicateHubDisplay` doesn't "listen" for updates to props to then update the `commsTitle` state.

## Solution

```
<DuplicateHubDisplay
  data={[
    inputValue,
    momentDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A"),
    textareaValue,
  ]}
/>
```

Yes, use an `useEffect` hook to react to prop value changes and update the local `commsTitle` state.

```
const DuplicateHubDisplay = ({ data }) => {
  const [inputValue] = data; // array destructuring assignment
  const [commsTitle, setCommsTitle] = useState(inputValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCommsTitle(inputValue);
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <input
      id="duplicatehub-title"
      onChange={(e) => setCommsTitle(e.target.value)}
      value={commsTitle}
      className="input"
      placeholder="Incident Title"
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit reactjs-input-onchange-not-updating-state]

## Solution 2

If you don't need to *actually* do anything with the `commsTitle` state you can assign `data[0]` as a `defaultValue` on the input and use the `data[0]` value as a React key so when the value updates from the parent React will remount/reset the input with a new default value.

```
const DuplicateHubDisplay = ({ data }) => {
  const [inputValue] = data; // array destructuring assignment

  return (
    <input
      key={inputValue}
      id="duplicatehub-title"
      defaultvalue={inputValue}
      className="input"
      placeholder="Incident Title"
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit reactjs-input-onchange-not-updating-state #2]

Comment: Unfortunately the solution doesn't work as the ```onChange={(e) =>{setCommsTitle(e.target.value)}} doesn't actually allow me to make changes to the input value. Doing a console.log on useEffect, it seems that it re-renders whatever is being set in the parent element and thus not allowing new values to be set

Comment: I made a little typo with useEffect, thanks heaps for your solution. The first one worked for me